# How do I increase the size of the text and pop-up window using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, popup, message

I have been working on creating a pop-up in order to direct specific end users to perform tasks before our helpdesk reaches out to them.

Currently I am using the following script:

```
$name = read-host "Enter computer name "
$msg = read-host "Enter your message "
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "msg * $msg" -ComputerName $name
```

I love it because it's pretty clean, and basic.
However the powers-that-be have requested that the pop-up window and text be larger, as they are concerned it will be quickly dismissed by our end-users.

I've combed through various forums looking for a solution, and hoping there is an option that's not too complicated.

I found a number of articles using $objForm, and many of them go pretty deep into creating custom boxes, which are a bit over my head.

Comment: You can't control the style of the dialog shown by ```msg``` unfortunately - it's built in to Windows. Tbh, I'd look at trying to automate sending a message via whatever email / chat application your company uses instead - you can include links and images then, and it'll have built-in features like multichannel notifications (desktop, mobile phone, toast popups, audible alerts etc), and allow users to do stuff like mute it during calls or screen share presentations with customers, etc, as well as have a message history they can read without accidentally dismissing it....

Answer (score 0):

[mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)'s tips provided in comments on the question and this answer are worth heeding.

In the absence of specialized tools, a potential solution is to use the [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) utility, which has the ability to run arbitrary commands in the context of the interactively logged-on user of a given remote computer.

The following is a - crude - proof of concept that may get you started:

- It uses [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, to run code that creates a WinForms form...
- ... and launches it via `psexec -i` on a given machine for interactive execution.

Note that while the PowerShell window hides itself on startup, it can only do so *after* having launched, which means that the console window will be briefly visible.
Avoiding this would require launching PowerShell via a GUI-subsystem executable that is capable of launching a console-subsystem executable such as `powershell.exe` *invisibly*.

**I cannot personally verify that this works across machines. Do let me know if it doesn't. See the comments on the `psexec` call below**.

```bash
# Define code that creates a WinForm form with a given message.
$code = {
  param($windowTitle, $message)
  Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
  $f = [Windows.Forms.Form] @{ StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'; Text = $windowTitle; Size = [Drawing.Size] @{ width = 800; height = 800 } }
  $f.Controls.AddRange(@(
    ([System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{ Text = $message; AutoSize = $true; Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new('Microsoft Sans Serif', 24) })
    ))
  $f.ShowDialog()
}
  
# Create a Base64-encoded form of the code, for use with powershell.exe  
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
  [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code)
)

# Ask for the target computer name and the message to display.
$computer = read-host "Enter computer name "
$msg = read-host "Enter your message "

# Determine the window title
$windowTitle = "Message from $env:USERNAME"

# Create a Base64-encoded form of the arguments to pass to the code.
$argsList = $windowTitle, $msg
$encodedArguments = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
  [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($argsList)
  )
) 

# Launch the code asynchronously on the target machine.
# !! You may have to provide -u <user> -p <password> here
# !! or use -s from an *elevated* session.     
psexec \\$computer -i -d powershell -noprofile -windowstyle Hidden -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand -EncodedArguments $encodedArguments
```

Comment: I don’t mean to bang a drum about it, but another reason to use email / chat instead is that tools like ```msg``` and remote-activated ```psexec``` require the target computer to have an active connection to the corporate network (on-prem / vpn / etc), whereas chat is generally cloud-based and will deliver the message as long as you have any old internet connection available…

Comment: Makes perfect sense, @mclayton.